# Envio de e-mail com vários remetentes e destinatários

Tags: php, phpmailer

Tenho registros no `MySql`, basicamente com colunas:

`usuario, emailusuario, descricao, responsavel, emailresponsavel`.

Preciso que, quando é feito um novo registro, envie um e-mail para o próprio usuário (`emailusuario`) e para o responsável (`emailresponsavel`).

Uso o PHPMailer, com uma conta `Gmail` para os envios, mas o problema é, que dessa forma o e-mail chega com e-mail de envio a conta Gmail e não com o e-mail do remetente (que seria o que faz o novo registro), mesmo setando o `$mail->SetFrom('xxx@xxx.com','usuario');`.

O `$mail->AddReplyTo()` funciona normalmente.

Gostaria de saber se isso ocorre porque é autenticado pelo `Gmail`, por ser `TLS`, ou algum outro motivo, e se há outra forma de fazer caso o problema for o `PHPMailer`. Preciso fazer isso, independente se tiver que trocar o `SMTP` ou `biblioteca`.

Script de envio:

```
require_once '/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$srvNome  = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$srvPort  = '587';
$srvEmail = 'emailpadraodoservidor@gmail.com';
$srvSenha = '****';

$emailAssunto       = 'NOVO REGISTRO';
$emailDestinatario  = $emailDest1; 
$titulo             = 'NOVO REGISTRO';

$conteudo = "teste";

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
    'verify_peer' => false,
    'verify_peer_name' => false,
    'allow_self_signed' => true
    )   
);
$mail->CharSet    = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Host       = $srvNome;
$mail->Port       = $srvPort;
$mail->Username   = $srvEmail;
$mail->Password   = $srvSenha;
$mail->AddReplyTo($emailRemetente,$remetenteNome);
$mail->SetFrom($emailRemetente,$remetenteNome);

$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Subject    = $emailAssunto;
$mail->Body       = $conteudo;

$mail->AddAddress($emailDestinatario);

if(!$mail->Send()) echo 'erro';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por questões de segurança do SMTP (Gmail no caso), a tag FROM (De:) sempre será preenchida com o e-mail da conta autenticada no SMTP, ou seja, do usuário do gmail no caso.

Você só conseguirá utilizar da forma pretendida se montar um servidor de SMTP próprio e enviar e-mail sem a autenticação no SMTP, via função mail() do PHP, pela porta 25. Atualmente a maioria dos provedores não aceitam mensagens oriundas da porta 25.