# PHPMailer com locaweb - Não está salvando os emails enviados na minha conta LocaWeb

Tags: php, phpmailer

Configurei o PHPMailer e está enviando corretamente os emails, porém na caixa de enviados da minha conta locaWeb esses emails enviados não ficam registrados. Tenho que fazer alguma configuração para isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tem como ficarem salvos, pois isso **é função do gerenciador de e-mails** que estiver usando.

Com o **PHPMailer**, não está usando nenhum, **somente autenticando** para enviar o e-mail, por isso não fica a cópia.

Algumas opções:

- Enviar **uma cópia a você**, e fazer um filtro no seu gerenciador, que identifique que o e-mail foi enviado por você, e então salve-o na pasta de enviados.
- Utilizar **IMAP**

---

#### Exemplo de envio de cópias

Enviando como cópia:

```
$mail->addCC('seuemail@example.com');
```

Enviando como cópia oculta:

```
$mail->addBCC('seuemail@example.com');
```

---

#### IMAP (exemplo com GMAIL)

```
# verificação se o e-mail foi enviado ou teve erros
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
    $save_result = save_mail($mail); # chama a função para envio da cópia via IMAP
    if ($save_result) {
        echo "Message saved!";
    }
}
 # função para chamar IMAP: https://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php
function save_mail($mail) {
    # Você pode enviar para a pasta de enviados ou alguma tag
    $path = "{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}[Gmail]/Sent Mail";
    # autenticando
    $imapStream = imap_open($path, $mail->Username, $mail->Password);
    # você pode usar imap_getmailboxes($imapStream, '/imap/ssl') para obter a lista de pastas e tags

    //Can be useful if you are trying to get this working on a non-Gmail IMAP server.
    $result = imap_append($imapStream, $path, $mail->getSentMIMEMessage());
    imap_close($imapStream);
    # retorna o resultado
    return $result;
}
```

[Exemplo via IMAP](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/pull/1117/commits/a0539a657b3b2566e341588261e3c80e0632a86c)

---

#### Mais

Alguns links sobre PHPMailer:

[PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

[Envio de e-mail com vários remetentes e destinatários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/280658/envio-de-e-mail-com-v%C3%A1rios-remetentes-e-destinat%C3%A1rios)

[Imagem em e-mail HTML no PHPMailer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/286570/imagem-em-e-mail-html-no-phpmailer)

[Diferenças de funções PHPMailer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/291042/92908)

Comment: Nossa, muito obrigado!! Vai ajudar demais.

Comment: @Trimander qualquer dúvida estamos aí! ✌️